# Trying to reload data for ASCollectionNode using AsyncDisplayKit / Texture

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, asyncdisplaykit, batch-fetching

I am trying to properly refresh an `ASCollectionNode` from `Texture`/`AsyncDisplayKit` whenever a user pulls down to refresh or decides to filter what they see.

By using `Texture`'s `shouldBatchFetch` and `willBeginBatchFetchWith` delegate and setting the `context` for batch fetching to `true`, the `ViewController` is initially able to batch fetch and load data. Likewise, as the user scrolls down (pagination API) I am able to load more data and everything works properly.

However, when I want to set my data manager empty and try to restart the process after initializing the `ASCollectionNode`, the batch fetching context seems to stop working even if I set it to true. I have tried different methods to properly "reload data" but have not had success with `Texture`'s asynchronous methods.

My failed attempts:

- I tried using `.reloadData()` but read that it was highly inefficient for `ASyncdisplaykit` and was deprecated. After clearing my data, calling reload data, then setting my `weNeedMoreContent` to `true`, causes an index out of bounds error.
  Screenshot: [reloadData Function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/auyei.png)
- When the user refreshed, I tried deleting all the current rows and then setting the `context` for batch fetching to `true` but nothing would happen either.

If anyone has any working methods they use for refreshing their `ASCollectionNode` please let me know!

[ASCollectionNode Delegate functions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4SOrf.png)

[Perform Batch Fetching and API helper functions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmye8.png)

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm having a similar issue.